# Using zCash through BitcoinJ

Tags: java, bitcoinj, dogecoin-api, zcash

Using zCash with BitcoinJ seems a reasonable advance for me, since I need to monitor various currencies for an academic project. Currently I run a full node with zCash along with BitcoinJ for Bitcoin and [Litecoin using network params](https://github.com/dogecoin/libdohj/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/libdohj/params) from the Dogecoin developers.

Out of the circumstance that zCash uses a lot of Bitcoin's Codebase I think this might be compatible, but unfortunately I'm unable to get it to work alone.

Here's my approach on ZcashMainNetParams (a lot it used from BitcoinJ's MainNetParams class together with zCashs chainparams.cpp):

```
public class ZcashMainNetParams extends AbstractZcashMainNetParams {
    public static final int MAINNET_MAJORITY_WINDOW = 1000;
    public static final int MAINNET_MAJORITY_REJECT_BLOCK_OUTDATED = 950;
    public static final int MAINNET_MAJORITY_ENFORCE_BLOCK_UPGRADE = 750;

    public ZcashMainNetParams() {
        super();
        interval = INTERVAL;
        targetTimespan = TARGET_TIMESPAN;
        maxTarget = Utils.decodeCompactBits(0x1d00ffffL);
        dumpedPrivateKeyHeader = 128;
        addressHeader = 0;
        p2shHeader = 5;
        acceptableAddressCodes = new int[] { addressHeader, p2shHeader };
        port = 8233;
        packetMagic = 0xf9beb4d9 /* netmagic same as BTC ??? */;
        bip32HeaderPub = 0x0488B21E; //The 4 byte header that serializes in base58 to "xpub".
        bip32HeaderPriv = 0x0488ADE4; //The 4 byte header that serializes in base58 to "xprv"

        majorityEnforceBlockUpgrade = MAINNET_MAJORITY_ENFORCE_BLOCK_UPGRADE;
        majorityRejectBlockOutdated = MAINNET_MAJORITY_REJECT_BLOCK_OUTDATED;
        majorityWindow = MAINNET_MAJORITY_WINDOW;

        genesisBlock = createGenesis(this);
        id = ID_MAINNET;
        subsidyDecreaseBlockCount = 210000;
        spendableCoinbaseDepth = 100;
        String genesisHash = genesisBlock.getHashAsString();
        checkState(genesisHash.equals("00040fe8ec8471911baa1db1266ea15dd06b4a8a5c453883c000b031973dce08"),
                genesisHash); /* updated */

        // This contains (at a minimum) the blocks which are not BIP30 compliant. BIP30 changed how duplicate
        // transactions are handled. Duplicated transactions could occur in the case where a coinbase had the same
        // extraNonce and the same outputs but appeared at different heights, and greatly complicated re-org handling.
        // Having these here simplifies block connection logic considerably.
        checkpoints.put(2500, Sha256Hash.wrap("00000006dc968f600be11a86cbfbf7feb61c7577f45caced2e82b6d261d19744")) /* updated */;
        checkpoints.put(15000, Sha256Hash.wrap("00000000b6bc56656812a5b8dcad69d6ad4446dec23b5ec456c18641fb5381ba")) /* updated */;
        checkpoints.put(67500, Sha256Hash.wrap("000000006b366d2c1649a6ebb4787ac2b39c422f451880bc922e3a6fbd723616")) /* updated */;

        dnsSeeds = new String[] {
                "dnsseed.z.cash",    // Zcash
                "dnsseed.str4d.xyz", // @str4d
                "dnsseed.znodes.org" // @bitcartel
        };
    }

    private static AltcoinBlock createGenesis(NetworkParameters params) {
        AltcoinBlock genesisBlock = new AltcoinBlock(params, 4L);
        Transaction t = new Transaction(params);
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Hex.decode
                    ("04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f");
            t.addInput(new TransactionInput(params, t, bytes));
            ByteArrayOutputStream scriptPubKeyBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Script.writeBytes(scriptPubKeyBytes, Hex.decode
                    ("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"));
            scriptPubKeyBytes.write(ScriptOpCodes.OP_CHECKSIG);
            t.addOutput(new TransactionOutput(params, t, COIN.multiply(50), scriptPubKeyBytes.toByteArray()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Cannot happen.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        genesisBlock.addTransaction(t);
        genesisBlock.setTime(1477641360L);
        genesisBlock.setDifficultyTarget(504365040L);
        genesisBlock.setNonce(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001257L);
        return genesisBlock;
    }

    private static ZcashMainNetParams instance;
    public static synchronized ZcashMainNetParams get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ZcashMainNetParams();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPaymentProtocolId() {
        return PAYMENT_PROTOCOL_ID_MAINNET;
    }
}
```

The abstract class is also re-used from the dogecoin developers:

```
public abstract class AbstractZcashMainNetParams extends NetworkParameters {

    /**
     * Scheme part for Bitcoin URIs.
     */
    public static final String BITCOIN_SCHEME = "zcash";
    public static final int REWARD_HALVING_INTERVAL = 210000;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractZcashMainNetParams.class);

    public AbstractZcashMainNetParams() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if we are at a reward halving point.
     * @param height The height of the previous stored block
     * @return If this is a reward halving point
     */
    public final boolean isRewardHalvingPoint(final int height) {
        return ((height + 1) % REWARD_HALVING_INTERVAL) == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if we are at a difficulty transition point.
     * @param height The height of the previous stored block
     * @return If this is a difficulty transition point
     */
    public final boolean isDifficultyTransitionPoint(final int height) {
        return ((height + 1) % this.getInterval()) == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkDifficultyTransitions(final StoredBlock storedPrev, final Block nextBlock,
                                           final BlockStore blockStore) throws VerificationException, BlockStoreException {
        final Block prev = storedPrev.getHeader();

        // Is this supposed to be a difficulty transition point?
        if (!isDifficultyTransitionPoint(storedPrev.getHeight())) {

            // No ... so check the difficulty didn't actually change.
            if (nextBlock.getDifficultyTarget() != prev.getDifficultyTarget())
                throw new VerificationException("Unexpected change in difficulty at height " + storedPrev.getHeight() +
                        ": " + Long.toHexString(nextBlock.getDifficultyTarget()) + " vs " +
                        Long.toHexString(prev.getDifficultyTarget()));
            return;
        }

        // We need to find a block far back in the chain. It's OK that this is expensive because it only occurs every
        // two weeks after the initial block chain download.
        final Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        Sha256Hash hash = prev.getHash();
        StoredBlock cursor = null;
        final int interval = this.getInterval();
        for (int i = 0; i < interval; i++) {
            cursor = blockStore.get(hash);
            if (cursor == null) {
                // This should never happen. If it does, it means we are following an incorrect or busted chain.
                throw new VerificationException(
                        "Difficulty transition point but we did not find a way back to the last transition point. Not found: " + hash);
            }
            hash = cursor.getHeader().getPrevBlockHash();
        }
        checkState(cursor != null && isDifficultyTransitionPoint(cursor.getHeight() - 1),
                "Didn't arrive at a transition point.");
        watch.stop();
        if (watch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) > 50)
            log.info("Difficulty transition traversal took {}", watch);

        Block blockIntervalAgo = cursor.getHeader();
        int timespan = (int) (prev.getTimeSeconds() - blockIntervalAgo.getTimeSeconds());
        // Limit the adjustment step.
        final int targetTimespan = this.getTargetTimespan();
        if (timespan < targetTimespan / 4)
            timespan = targetTimespan / 4;
        if (timespan > targetTimespan * 4)
            timespan = targetTimespan * 4;

        BigInteger newTarget = Utils.decodeCompactBits(prev.getDifficultyTarget());
        newTarget = newTarget.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(timespan));
        newTarget = newTarget.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(targetTimespan));

        if (newTarget.compareTo(this.getMaxTarget()) > 0) {
            log.info("Difficulty hit proof of work limit: {}", newTarget.toString(16));
            newTarget = this.getMaxTarget();
        }

        int accuracyBytes = (int) (nextBlock.getDifficultyTarget() >>> 24) - 3;
        long receivedTargetCompact = nextBlock.getDifficultyTarget();

        // The calculated difficulty is to a higher precision than received, so reduce here.
        BigInteger mask = BigInteger.valueOf(0xFFFFFFL).shiftLeft(accuracyBytes * 8);
        newTarget = newTarget.and(mask);
        long newTargetCompact = Utils.encodeCompactBits(newTarget);

        if (newTargetCompact != receivedTargetCompact)
            throw new VerificationException("Network provided difficulty bits do not match what was calculated: " +
                    Long.toHexString(newTargetCompact) + " vs " + Long.toHexString(receivedTargetCompact));
    }

    @Override
    public Coin getMaxMoney() {
        return MAX_MONEY;
    }

    @Override
    public Coin getMinNonDustOutput() {
        return Transaction.MIN_NONDUST_OUTPUT;
    }

    @Override
    public MonetaryFormat getMonetaryFormat() {
        return new MonetaryFormat();
    }

    @Override
    public int getProtocolVersionNum(final ProtocolVersion version) {
        return version.getBitcoinProtocolVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public BitcoinSerializer getSerializer(boolean parseRetain) {
        return new BitcoinSerializer(this, parseRetain);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUriScheme() {
        return BITCOIN_SCHEME;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMaxMoney() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Problem here is basically the generation of the genesis block. I'm unable to forge it with the right hash. I believe it has to do with the transaction I try to understand in the [chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L80-L82) of zCash. However my genesis block has the hash of 
`e88b11fd3581e170f86db9c574f65c0ada3216e126011ac968869f1b64ea4c4a` instead of the required
`00040fe8ec8471911baa1db1266ea15dd06b4a8a5c453883c000b031973dce08`

Thanks for any kind of help, even including a reasonable conclusion that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr Your code isn't accounting for the format of the Zcash block header, which is different to both Bitcoin and most altcoins. You need to add the `hashReserved` and `nSolution` fields, and make `nNonce` 256 bits instead of 32.

---

Let's assume for now that all you want to do is parse the Zcash blockchain. For that, you'll need to make two changes:

- Modify the transaction parsing code to handle our [v2 transactions](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h#L359-L365) (containing JoinSplits).
- Modify the block header to match our format (what you question asks about).

The Zcash block header is the [regular Bitcoin serialization](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/primitives/block.h#L44-L52) of the following:

```cpp
int32_t nVersion;
uint256 hashPrevBlock;
uint256 hashMerkleRoot;
uint256 hashReserved;
uint32_t nTime;
uint32_t nBits;
uint256 nNonce;
std::vector<unsigned char> nSolution;
```

Most of these work the same way as they do in Bitcoin. The ones which are different to Bitcoin and most other altcoins, which you will need to implement in BitcoinJ, are:

- `hashReserved` - a simple field, currently always zero (but don't assume that).
- `nNonce` - 256 bits instead of 32, but otherwise has the same function.
- `nSolution` - this is the Equihash solution in each block header. It is serialized as a (Bitcoin-style) vector, so you don't technically need to know how to parse its internals; you can just read the length field and then that many bytes (currently 1344, but don't assume this).

Implementing the above will enable you to parse Zcash block headers. If you want to be able to validate them, you will also need to fully parse `nSolution`, and then implement the [Equihash validator](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/crypto/equihash.cpp#L722-L768) and the [difficulty adjustment algorithm](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/pow.cpp#L23-L82).

For completeness, `nSolution` is the bit-concatenation of the Equihash solution indices, represented as a byte array. Given the Equihash parameters `N` and `K`, there are `2^K` indices, each of length `(N/(K+1))+1` bits. For the current parameters of `(N, K) = (200, 9)`, each solution index is `(200/(9+1))+1 = 21` bits, and `nSolution` contains `2^9 = 512` indices. This is a total of 10752 bits when concatenated, or 1344 bytes.

Source: Zcash engineer (I originally posted this from an old SE account).